# Unable to read GET variable when used in $page_content

Tags: php, get

I have a file called `productFocus.php` where I use the GET variable ID: `$id = $_GET["id"];`
However this page is used in the `product.php` file in the following manner:

**product.php**

```
<?php
    $page_content = 'productFocus.php'; // $id = $_GET["id"];
    include('master.php');
?>
```

**productFocus.php**

```
<?php
    include "db/db.php";
    $id = $_GET["id"];
    $product = get_product_by_id($id);
?>

<div class="product-focus">
    <h3><?php echo $product->name ?></h3>
    <img src="/images/products/<?php echo $product->image ?>">
    <div id="description">
        <h4>Productinformatie</h4>
        <p><?php echo $product->description ?></p>
        <h4>Partners</h4>
        <table>
            <?php
                foreach($product->partners_obj as $partner) {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href=<?php echo $partner->$product_url ?> target="_blank">
                        <img id="partner" src="/images/partners/<?php echo $partner->image ?>">
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href=<?php echo $partner->$product_url ?> target="_blank"><?php $partner->$product_price ?></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php
                }
            ?>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**master.php**

```
//HTML code
...
 <?php include($page_content);?>
...
//HTML code
```

When I browse to `productFocus.php?id=324324` I can read the GET variable, but when I browse to `product.php?id=324324` I do not have access to the GET variable ID.

Is there an elegant way to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you explain better and, please, show some code? Do you mean that you want to pass the `id` from `productFocus.php?id=...` to `product.php`?

Comment: All the relevant code is there...

Comment: It depends on how `$page_content` is actually used. You might **perhaps** be able to fix this with `$page_content='productFocus.php'.(array_key_exists('id',$_GET)?"?id={$_GET['id']}":"");`, but lacking additional information, there's no guarantee.

Comment: Can you post the code for each file?

Comment: I don't see you including the productFocus.php file in product.php.

Comment: @David: no, it *is not* all there. The relevant code appears to be in `master.php`, wherever it refers to `$page_content`. You might want to post a snippet of those lines.

Comment: Thanks. l've added more code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the GET variable before you call the product details in the prodcts.php file before regular page load.

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['id'])) {

    // GET PRODUCT DATA

}else{

    // LOAD PRODUCTS PAGE

}

?>
```

As for getting the product details, I would suggest writing the separate call to the database, but if you just need to load page content, you are not calling it properly:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];    
$fileurl = 'products.php?id='.$id;
$pagecontent = file_get_contents('$fileurl');
```

Comment: Passing the data works fine now, however the master.php wont load :(

Comment: your master.php file has to start with php tags, even if they're empty and have no code in them before html tags. Otherwise the server tries to load php file and then runs into html tag, thinking this is where the php ends :)

Comment: I use the same code in index.php and there it works fine
`<?php
    $page_content = 'products.php';
    include('master.php');
?>`

Comment: do you have $page_content variable before calling master.php? they way it looks, it's not declared in master.php file, it's just called. If the page calling master.php file doesn't have $page_content (or if it doesn't set it before calling master), it won't show anything, you could check if there is any with the if statement in the master.php file just to be sure.